# Plotting graph using database asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page graphics.aspx where I have the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="graficos.aspx.cs" Inherits="graficos" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center">

        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"  >
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>  

        </asp:Chart>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the page graphics.cs where I have the following code that does the query in the database and assigns to the chart:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class graficos : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSQL"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Valor, DataHoraAtualizacao FROM EntradaEstado INNER JOIN Entrada ON EntradaEstado.IDEntrada = Entrada.IDEntrada WHERE Entrada.Descricao = N'" + Request.Form["descricao"].ToString() + "'");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "DataHoraAtualizacao";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Valor";
        Chart1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }


}
```

My graph is not being plotted, it seems like I need to assign the datasource to asp.net code and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: your SQL code is vulnerable to injection attacks. Do not create queries by naively chaining strings together like this. Your data can be hacked - stolen, deleted or modified - by some malicious input. Instead use SQL parameters to better protect your database. http://bobby-tables.com/ has a good introduction to the topic and some examples using C#/ADO.NET.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Make sure your query is returning data. Use your debugger and inspect `dt` contents.

Comment: Thanks, i got it!